# Stop child product discounts applying on Bundle product

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

We have about 20 simple products which have a Cart Price Rule for buy 4 and get 10% off.

We also have bundle products which use these products but are already discounted. However when the rule applies it also applies to the bundle - which we do not want.

The rules appear to work correctly for "Conditions" - if you have 4 bundles only the rule does not get triggered.

However, if you have 4 of the simple products and 1 or more of the bundles the rule applies to them all, giving the bundle a discount.

We have the "conditions" set up the same as "Actions > Apply the rule only to cart items..."

Conditions (appears to be ok):

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total quantity  equals or greater than  4  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
Category  is  111
```

Apply to (where I think the issue is):

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is  111  
Exclude from Promotions  is not  Yes
```

We have tried doing various combinations and different categories, and as you can see even set up a new attribute and excluding by that - but the discount still applies to bundles!

How can we have it set up where by simple product discounts don't apply to bundles?

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation as you.
I fixed it by using SKU (Parent only) in the rules.